# Adding "wikimedia unlabelled layer" as basemap option in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps

In QGIS, I have used the OpenLayers plugin to make a number of basemaps, including the Wikimedia labelled and unlabelled layers available. I am seeking to find a way to use these Wikimedia layers as basemaps in ArcMap.

Is there a way this layer can be accessed from ArcGIS Online or could somebody show me how to download tiles?

I am using ArcMap 10.8.